# Which data structure should be used for reading and storing about 5 million entries from a text file

Tags: c#, data-structures, text-files

I have to deal with two text files, both about 1 GB and compare the data in the files. Which data structure should I use for storing the data? Comparing such huge records using dictionaries/hash tables gives out of memory exception. Or should I read and store the data in a database?

Comment: What is the format of these files? Comma-separated values, one record per line? What kind of comparisons would you like to perform? Are the records sorted or is it possible to sort them?

Comment: You haven't told us what you need to *do* with the data. That dictates the answer, really...

Comment: The records in the file are all in one line without any delimiter. I have separated the records based on a Regex(A single record is Alphanumeric). Then I have to check whether a record present in one file exists in the second file or not.

Comment: Is there a way to sort the records? Maybe you could sort them alphabetically, line-by-line.

Comment: Sorting in the file itself wont be possible since I just have one continuous chunk of(about 10^9 alphabets and numbers) data from which the records have to be extracted. To sort them, I'll have to extract and copy them to the main memory

Comment: No you do not need to copy all the data to main memory to sort it, this is exactly one advantage of merge sort!

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally, a Database would be best for this sort of behaviour, they're designed to deal with this much data and have had more work put into optimizing for that scenario then you're likely to be able to do.

You could use an InProcess SQL like SqlLite or even a NoSql scenario such as Raven or MongoDB as an alternative though.

Comment: @russ Depends a little on the "compare" operations

Answer (score 2):

.NET Framework 4 provides [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) feature (heh, old good win32 API provide such feature since many years), you can map difefrent part of file in the separate segment and process them simultaneously.

> To work with a memory-mapped file, you must create a view of the
>   entire memory-mapped file or a part of it. You can also create
>   multiple views to the same part of the memory-mapped file, thereby
>   creating concurrent memory. For two views to remain concurrent, they
>   have to be created from the same memory-mapped file.
>
> Multiple views may also be necessary if the file is greater than the
>   size of the application’s logical memory space available for memory
>   mapping (2 GB on a 32-bit computer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a prime example of using a database. Depending on your structure a script will be needed define its layout to add the vlaues into the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort on some attribute in the records that is also used for your comparison, you could use [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) to sort the files, and the scan them in parallel with no need to store the entire data in main memory.

Checking if a record in the first file is also present in the second file has a complexity of O(n^2) if you use two nested loops. But if the files are sorted, you can use one single loop. In addition, merge sort has complexity O(n log n). The overall complexity is O(n log n), which is better than O(n^2). [Here](http://dzmitryhuba.blogspot.com/2010/08/external-merge-sort.html) is an implementation of merge sort in C#.

I think you can achieve the same result (in terms of speed) using a database, if records are indexed.

Comment: The problem I am facing is because of the large n. Copying all the data in main memory for even O(n log n) comparisons will give out of memory exception.

Comment: With merge sort you do not need to copy all the data in main memory. And when the data is sorted, you do not need to read in the whole files to compare them, you can read them one record at a time.